# Socket IO doesn't send array

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I am trying to show all usernames online with socket.io:
Here is the server side code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
   });
var send="dsf";
var usernames=[];
var users=0;
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
users++;
    console.log(users);
io.emit("online",users);
socket.on("new",function(username)
{
    console.log(username+"is connected");
    socket.username=username;
    usernames[username]=username;
    console.log(usernames);
    io.emit("users",
    {total: users,
    names:usernames});
    }

);

         socket.on('disconnect' ,function(){
          users--;
         console.log(users);

            });
       });


             http.listen(3000, function(){
          console.log('listening on *:3000');
      });
```

And here is the client side:

```
<script>
var socket = io();
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var name=prompt("What is your name?","");
 if (name!="")
 {
 socket.emit("new",name);
 }
       socket.on("online",function(users)
{
alert(users);
})
socket.on("users",function(usernames)
{
alert(usernames.names.length);
});
  });
</script>
```

What I want is simply to show all connected usernames when a user log in. I am failing to send that usernames array who contains all the connected usernames(I know that I must delete a user on disconnect but I will do that at the end )

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(usernames)` instead of putting the `alert` statement?

Comment: Also, can you please post your `index.html` code too?

Comment: @DavidR did you find a solution?

Comment: @DavidR like this(check the newest answer please)?

Comment: @DavidR THANKS BRO, You are the best.

Comment: Glad that it worked! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `usernames` array assignment from,

```
usernames[username]=username;
```

To,

```
usernames.push(username);
```

which will resolve the issue. I have tested this and working fine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```html
        <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io();
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var name=prompt("What is your name?","");
 if (name!="")
 {
 socket.emit("new",name);
 }
socket.on("online",function(users)
{
alert(users);
})
socket.on("users",function(usernames)
{
alert(usernames.names.length);
});
  });
</script>
  <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
var send="dsf";
var usernames=[];
var users=0;
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    users++;
        console.log(users);
    io.emit("online",users);
    socket.on("new",function(username)
    {
    console.log(username+"is connected");
    socket.username=username;
    usernames.push(username);
    console.log(usernames);
    }
    );

socket.on('disconnect' ,function(){
users--;
console.log(users);

});
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```